# How to install a program with a graphical installer in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation, java

I want to install yEd
(http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html).

It has a .sh installer which first unpacks and then starts a graphical installer.

I have tried sudo and gksudo but so far without success. The installer terminates with:
'Could not display the GUI. This application needs access to an X Server.'

Comment: What version of **Ubuntu** are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this tutorial: (based on download of Java version, instead of .sh)

[yEd on Ubuntu](http://grahamis.com/blog/2011/11/07/yed-on-ubuntu/)

**---- ---- UPDATE ---- ----**

The **.sh** file, once downloaded, runs fine on **Ubuntu 12.04** (64bit).

After install, just run this at command line:

```
~/yEd/yEd &
```

With a little more effort, I can probably get a Unity icon (and get it docked).

Comment: The linked tutorial was really useful and what I ended up doing, thanks!

Comment: The **.sh** method installs to **~/yEd**, complete with .desktop file (icon) and works fine.  But, this is **not** the preferred method for install on Ubuntu.  A hybrid between the two methods would be better.  I **recommend** the **Java** download (and tutorial) for now.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to:

- switch to a terminal by CTRL+ALT+F1
- type 'sudo ldm stop'.
- cd to the directory where the script is located and
- run it with `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

With me, it just works as follows:

Download the `.sh` file, example:  `yEd-3.10.1_32-bit_setup.sh`
Open a Terminal(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
Navigate to the location where the `.sh` file is downloaded.
execute command:
    `sudo sh yEd-3.10.1_32-bit_setup.sh`

Then follow instructions, and its done

My Ubuntu version: 12.04 LTS